# Transform data with an arbitrary function at chart level with Pyqtgraph

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I'm creating a pyQt application to display some sensor data in real-time with `pyqtgraph`: I'd like to create functional blocks that can be adapted and used for different purposes and somewhat clean and clear with how we interact with the data.

In want my application to treat the data in three levels:

- **raw data**: this is the data coming from my sensor. It can be from a MQTT topic, a streaming plateform, a REST API, whatever.
- **synthetic data**: this is data the user can generate when he wants to apply transforms that make sense with the context of the data (for example: convert °C to °F). This data stream is reinjected with the raw data and can be displayed as well.
- **representation of the data**: these are transforms that don't make sense with the context of the data and are completely abstract (example: add an offset). It really belongs to the chart and not the data.

So far, I've been able to apply my first transform on the representation of the data with the offset:

```py
def update_offset_pos(i):
    step = 0.05
    self.curves[i].setPos(
        self.curves[i].pos().x(), 
        self.curves[i].pos().y() + step
    )
```

The `setPos()` method really answer my needs because it is completly abstract and doesn't apply to the data fed, but rather the representation in the chart.

Now, I would like to go further and apply other transforms on my data. For example, I wanted to implement a modulus. In the pyqt application, I can right click on the chart, select `Plot Options > Transforms > Power Spectrum (FFT)` and a bunch of other ones. This means there must be a system of transforms I can use?

The only thing I've been able to do is this:

```py
def update_chart(self):
    '''
    Updates the chart
    '''
    for curve in self.curves:
        curve.setData(self.x, deque(map(lambda x: x % modulus if modulus!= 0 else x, self.buffer)))
```

This is wrong because I'm hijacking my `update_chart` method to apply a transform. What I would like to have, is something similar to the offset, meaning:

```py
def modData(data, mod):
    return data % mod

def add_mod_transform(i):
    self.curves[i].setTransform(modData)
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: See [ask]. It's unclear. What is the type of the ```curves[i]```? The ```PlotDataItem```? Post a [mre]. Anyway, why not define a class derived from the ```PlotDataItem```?